# Query Previous year records

Tags: apex, soql

Is there any way to get the records of Asset that have InstallDate of last year.
I am doing this way.

> Integer preYear = system.today().year()-1;
>
> preYearAssetList = [Select id from Asset Where
>   installDate.year() = preYear];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the below

```
system.debug('***'+[Select id from Asset Where installDate = LAST_YEAR]);
```

For current year it will be THIS_YEAR

For Next year it will be NEXT_YEAR

Check all combinations in this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_dates.htm&language=en)

Comment: Thanks its working can you please tell me what I have to do for current year and next year??

Comment: Updated the answer .